# Creation of a new command so that you do not have to write a certain caption by hand

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, captions

I have a problem. My figures should have a caption like `<Caption> - Own representation, based on [1].` As you can see I am writing `Own representation, based on [<literature>]`.
Is there an option to create a new command,e.g. `\captionauto[CRIPS-DM]{~\cite{einstein}}` what deliveries the same output as `\caption[CRIPS-DM]{CRIPS-DM - Own representation, based on ~\cite{einstein}}`. So that I do not have always write `- Own representation, based on` by hand?

Hint: `- Own representation, based on [<literature>]` should not appear at the list of figures.

Is there an option to create a new command that I do not have to write `- Own representation, based on` by hand?

```
\caption[CRIPS-DM]{CRIPS-DM - Own representation, based on ~\cite{einstein}}
```

```
\captionauto[CRIPS-DM]{~\cite{einstein}}
```

MVP

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@online{ApoG,
  Address = {03.08.2013},
  Edition = {15.10.1980},
  Publisher = {juris GmbH},
  Title = {ApoG - Gesetz {\"u}ber das Apothekenwesen},
  Url = {www.juris.de/purl/gesetze/_ges/ApoG},
  Year = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[%
backend=bibtex      % biber or bibtex
%,style=authoryear    % Alphabeticalsch
,style=numeric-comp  % numerical-compressed
,sorting=none        % no sorting
,sortcites=true      % some other example options ...
,block=none
,indexing=false
,citereset=none
,isbn=true
,url=true
,doi=true            % prints doi
,natbib=true         % if you need natbib functions
]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
    urlseen = {aufgerufen am}
}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}  % better than \bibliography

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption[CRIPS-DM]{CRIPS-DM - Own representation, based on ~\cite{einstein}}
    \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

%Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper ~\cite{einstein} are physics related items. Lorem 
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @campa done. I think it was a bug.

Comment: Try this: `\newcommand\testcaption[3][]{\caption[{#2}]{#2 - Own representation, based on~\cite{#3}\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\label{#1}\fi}`. Has an optional argument to also set a `\label`, so `\testcaption{CRIPS-DM}{einstein}`, and if you need a `\label` use `\testcaption[label]{CRIPS-DM}{einstein}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you really need an optional parameter. As far as I understand you want the first argument of your `\captionauto` to be used as short caption, and then as long caption followed by the citation. Something like

```
\newcommand*{\citecaption}[2]{%
   \caption[#1]{#1 --- Own representation, based on~\cite{#2}.}%
}
```

which you would then use as

```
\citecaption{CRIPS-DM}{einstein}
```